Apply weight to one feature based on another one for training a regression model
I have 1000 items that have a numerical feature y, the ground truth that I want to predict.
Each item has another feature c that is in some way related to y.
For each item, I can take 11 samples over a period of time.  A sample is a numeric value that fluctuates around the real value y.
I have added another column weight to my data frame where the value is the number of samples for the particular item minus one divided by 11, in other words a range from 0 to 10/11.
Finally, I have added a column 'mean' that is the average of the samples taken before the current sample. This is initially 0 for each item.  and it gradually converges into the direction of y.
How should I train this model? My initial idea was this:

Write the average of all samples into another column total.
Drop the column sample.
Configure the model in such a way that it takes the weight into account when considering the mean.

Is step 3 possible at all? And does it make sense or is the model able to learn these relations itself? In that case, does it make sense to average the previous samples at all?
A more realistic example could be a professional sports league. y would be the ranking of a team at the end of the season.  c would be some team feature like the net value of the team in money. The samples would then be the performances of each team during the season.
The following Python code emulates such a data set. I have also added scatter diagrams for that data.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nitems = 100
nsamples = 11

np.random.seed(42)

y = np.random.normal(0, 1, nitems)
# Some random relation.
c = (y - 1) ** 2 + 2 + np.random.normal(0, 1.0, nitems)

# Repeat each row nsamples times.
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'y': y, 'c': c })
indices = np.repeat(df.index, nsamples)
df = df.loc[indices].reset_index(drop=True)

df['weight'] = (df.index % nsamples) / nsamples

# Generate samples with more noise than the feature c.
df['sample'] = df['y'] + np.random.normal(scale=0.6, size = nitems * nsamples)

# Calculate the cumulative mean of 'sample' with weights less than the current weight
groups = df.groupby(np.arange(nitems * nsamples) // nsamples)
def calculate_mean(group):
    samples = group['sample'].values
    mean = np.zeros_like(samples, dtype=float)
    for i in range(1, len(samples)):
        mean[i] = np.mean(samples[:i])
    return mean
df['mean'] = np.concatenate(groups.apply(calculate_mean).values)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(df)


